# Missing bash prompt

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

My bash prompt is missing as shown on the image. I'm not even sure how to open the .bash_profile since dot files are hidden in the finder.
I restarted the machine to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Can we presume if you type something like `open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile` nothing happens?

Comment: correct, nothing happens. open command nor nano command gives any output. I am logged in as a user, not as admin. but it was working before :(

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside the problem with your shell - there are lots of ways to get to a clean prompt:

- make a new user account and use that command line to become root: `sudo -s` and then go in and nuke/fix/move your files

You also could try booting to single user mode, mounting the filesystem read+write and cleaning things. I'd go the new user route since you can log out of your user without needing a restart.

Answer (score 2):

If its a problem with your bash startup scripts you should be able to use the terminal menu item "New Command..." and run "bash --noprofile --norc".

But it may not be this.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change your login shell? System prefs > users and groups > unlock, bottom left > right click your username > advanced options > login shell.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + C.

might work. works for me. glad it did!